# Yii2 Module 'pdo_pgsql' already loaded - not doubled in php.ini

Tags: php, yii2

My Yii2 app on VPS gives "module pdo-pgsql already loaded" error.
I've checked my php.ini file and the module it's not doubled loaded.
Can it be resolved from Yii2 configuration?
I didn't found anything on google to help me with this error. It seems like the only possible reason for error is just double loaded in php.ini.
Am I missing something here?
Thank you

Comment: show your error message

Comment: show php --ini result

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the inclusion in php.ini

Maybe the PHP version you are using is compiled with the module already included.